# What does the "Justify Distributed" alignment really do?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In *Excel 2010* in *Alignment* tab of *Format Cells* there is a check box named *Justify Distributed*.
What does this option do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Horizontal Alignment set to 'Distributed', then checking the Justify Distributed checkbox will make characters in the cell to the left of the space character left aligned, and characters on the right of the space character right aligned.

This is what content in a Justify Distributed cell looks like.  The cell contains:  'the quick':

[image]

It's like having left and right justification in the same cell.

EDIT:

The difference between Justify Distributed and Distributed only comes into play with a multi-line cell.  In a Justify Distributed cell, the last line of text is fully justified.  See second attached image where row 2 is Distributed and row 3 is Justify Distributed. [image: Justify Distributed multi-line]

Comment: But there isn't apparently any difference between that state and the Horizontal Distributed (if we uncheck the justify distributed).

Comment: I tested that text. The A2 is not Distributed! While the A3 is Justify distributed. If you apply the Distributed over A2 you'll see there isn't any difference between them. Thanks for your trying to help.

Comment: oops, yep, I was testing with the 'Indent' value in row 2.  You're right.  Justify Distributed does nothing. Interestingly, in vba, it looks like there are only constants for 'center', 'distributed', 'justify', 'left' and 'right', not 'justify distributed', so I think its a 'not yet implemented' feature.

Answer (score 0):

Justify Distributed is a type of alignment wherein the first and last word of each line is aligned to the left and right margin respectively. As for the case of Excel, it will align to the left and right borders of that row. Excel will also be the one responsible for the spacing between words so they'll be distributed evenly across the line.

If you choose Distributed (Indent), you can choose what value your Indent should be. Indent tells how many indent spaces will you have after your left border and before your right border. Checking the "Justify Distributed" box is the same as keeping this number to 0 wherein the first and last word is just aligned to the left and right borders respectively.

Checking the "Justify Distributed" disables the "Indent" option and this ensures that there are no spaces between the left border and the first word; and the last word and the right border.

Comment: No. It doesn't disable it. It only grays the _Indent_ but using it is still possible. Thanks for your answer.